# pandas pivot dataframe, but add unseen values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I have 2 dataframes:

```
purchases = pd.DataFrame([['Alice', 'sweeties', 4],
                      ['Bob', 'chocolate', 5],
                      ['Alice', 'chocolate', 3],
                      ['Claudia', 'juice', 2]],
                    columns=['client', 'item', 'quantity'])

goods = pd.DataFrame([['sweeties', 15],
                  ['chocolate', 7],
                  ['juice', 8],
                  ['lemons', 3]], columns=['good', 'price'])
```

and I want to transform purchases with cols and indexes alike at this photo:

[image]

My first thought was to use pivot:

```
purchases.pivot(columns="item", values="quantity")
```

Output:

[image]

The problem is: I also need the lemons column in the pivot result because it's present in the goods dataframe (just filled with None values).

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain with `reindex`:

```
purchases.pivot(columns="item", values="quantity").reindex(goods['good'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
good  sweeties  chocolate  juice  lemons
0          4.0        NaN    NaN     NaN
1          NaN        5.0    NaN     NaN
2          NaN        3.0    NaN     NaN
3          NaN        NaN    2.0     NaN
```

Comment: A really beautiful way to solve the problem, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`df.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
In [3626]: x = goods.merge(purchases, left_on='good', right_on='item', how='left')
In [3628]: x['total'] = x.price * x.quantity # you can tweak this calculation

In [3634]: res = x[['good', 'client', 'total']].pivot('client', 'good', 'total').dropna(how='all').fillna(0)

In [3635]: res
Out[3635]: 
good     chocolate  juice  lemons  sweeties
client                                     
Alice         21.0    0.0     0.0      60.0
Bob           35.0    0.0     0.0       0.0
Claudia        0.0   16.0     0.0       0.0
```

Comment: @АрсенийПроценко Please let me know if the answer worked for you.

Comment: thanks for the response, seems to work at this example, didn't test on other data (because of lack of them)